# How to pass flash attributes one controller to anoher in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would to know how to pass a flash attributes from one controller to another  in Spring MVC
I have the following code: first controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateWeekdays",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateWeekdays(HttpServletRequest request,final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    String weekDays[] = request.getParameterValues("status");
    timetableService.updateWeekDays(weekDays);

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message","updated successfully.");
    return "redirect:/./login/home";
}
```

and second controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView redirectHome(HttpServletRequest request) {


    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Home");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

what i am missing,
when i write two methods in same controller its working fine

Comment: Please explain your question in detail and  actually what to do.

Comment: in first controller am trying to update weekdays and after updation redirect to home through second controller with success message,
redirection working fine but couldn't get success message on page, when write two method in same controller its working fine